# How do I use the QTable? Adding, editing, removing and retrieving rows

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtablewidget

How do you use the QTable object. I have searched the internet and the examples don't really seem to make sense. Do you just create a new row within the extended class. It all seems fussing. How do you retreive, edit and delete rows. Is there any extensions that could be used like

```
QRowObject *row = table->add("Main Title");
row->addSubColumnText("Second column");
otherRow = table->getRowByIndex(table->selectedIndex);
otherRow.remove;
```

How would any implement that?

Any extra information needed just ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QTable is pretty old. You might be looking for [QTableWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtablewidget.html). If you want to get into the whole 'Model-View' arch thing, look into [QTableView](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtableview.html).

```
// inside e.g. a QMainWindow, parent could be 'this'
QTableWidget *widget = new QTableWidget(parent); 
// add to layout etc, then:

QStringList headerLabels;
headerLabels << "First Column" << "Second Column";
widget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headerLabels);
// here you would add data, then:
widget->removeRow(table->currentRow());
```